# Can I configure environment specific content?

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi, isapi

In the same way that you can generate specific content based on browser type is there a way to generate specific content based on the server running PHP without reference to the server or site name?

For example, a way for PHP to automatically detect the environment it was in and configure things like DB connections, ini_set for errors etc. depending if it was a development, ITS, UAT or production environment.

The 2 ways I thought of were to recognise an HTTP header indicating development and QA environments or to have custom properties in php.ini.

I have woken up slightly and found out the php function to read the http headers but php overrides anything I set in the web server and I do not know if they can be set in php.ini at all.

I have no idea if it is possible to add custom values to php.ini but I had a test and ini_get would not find it (I had restarted the web server after changing php.ini of course).

Comment: I do not want to use server name because there may be any number of dev machines, the QA server names may change etc.

$_ENV would seem to be the way to go if I can set them via IIS which is what I have to work with as the web server.

Comment: After some research I could find no way to add environment variables with ISAPI so moved to fastcgi (I was planning on that anyway). I have followed the instructions in configuring fastcgiext.ini and added environment variables there and restarted IIS but $_ENV is still empty.

As an additional note our current setup breaks one of the cardinal rules of the production cycle in that the dev and ITS sites are IIS 5, UAT is likely to be IIS 6 and production IIS 7. I am hoping this will be resolved bofore there actually is a production site but it means I am currentltly limited to IIS 5.

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] goes by what the calling client calls the server, not what the server itself is called.  If you connect by IP rather than hostname, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will be the IP address.  If you set up an alternate name in your hosts file, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will be that, etc.  May be useful to consider.

Comment: I finally sorted it. The initial documentation for fastCGI failed to mention that you don't just assign your sites an arbitary number you need to get the IIS site ID of the site. Once I had that vital piece of information I could use getenv("varname") to retrieve the value. $_ENV is still empty but since I have a method I am happy.

I was avoiding $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] so that anyone could set up a devel site and not rely on localhost to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FastCGI on IIS you can set Environment variables. They do not seem to be available to $_ENV but can be retrieved with getenv("varname").

To configure FastCGI environment variables in IIS 5 or 6 you need to edit: 
C:\%systemdrive%\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.ini

For example:

```
[Types]
php=d:\Dev\PHP\php-cgi.exe
php:1=PHP Site 1
*=Wildcard Mapping

[d:\Dev\PHP\php-cgi.exe]
QueueLength=999
MaxInstances=20
InstanceMaxRequests=500

[PHP Site 1]
ExePath=d:\Dev\PHP\php-cgi.exe
EnvironmentVars=PHPRC:d:\Dev\PHP\,SiteType:Developer
```

In this instance it is IIS 5 so there is only one site and the site ID is 1 as indicated in line 2 of [Types].

On IIS 6 you may have multiple sites and the following link tells you how to find the Site ID: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/07/29/how-to-find-the-siteid-in-iis5-and-iis6.aspx.

IIS 7 can be configured via the UI apparently once the Administration Pack for IIS 7 has been installed.

Answer (score 4):

you can specify an environment variable in apache (conf, vhost, .htaccess or as an httpd daem) and then acces it via the ˆ$_ENVˆsuperglobal

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to load different settings for different servers:

```
switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
case 'web-host': case '10.0.0.208':
    # Set DB Settings
case 'mydomain.com': default:
    # Live server settings
}
```

Not had a problem with it so far

Comment: You said without access to the server or site name - does this mean that $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is not available?

Answer (score 0):

$_ENV / http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that hasn't been mentioned yet would be to create a server-specific (but with the same name) configuration file that would be included in the beginning of your site script. In that server-specific config file you could set configuration variables as constants. That way, if there was a 'generic' configuration file loaded later, its values could be overridden in the server-specific configuration file as constants can't be redefined. You would want to either exclude the server-specific configuration file name from the synchronizations, or keep it in a path outside of the main content so that it is not accidentally overwritten.

For this purpose you can even configure Constant Arrays with help of [Constant Array 2 class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6760-PHP-Enhanced-declaration-of-array-values-as-constants.html).

When server-specific configuration files are used you don't have to worry about the current SERVER_NAME -- this makes it easier for you to define the intended environment regardless of the current system name which could be handy also for QA purposes.